# Current Date and time ("Wall" Date and time) for any timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Alright, I understand that this problem has been asked a lot of times at lot of places, but I couldn't get this working yet. I tried `java.util.Date` as well as `JodaTime` APIs.

My question is on how to return the current date and time considering the timezone where my app is running. Here is a method which I wrote to return me the current Date time. The problem is, it is always returning me the UTC time.

```
private String getCurrentDate()
{
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM hh:mm");
    String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate);
    return dateNow;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String getCurrentDate()
{
      final DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
      format.setTimeZone(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
      return format.format(new Date());
}
```

This should do the job. The tricky part of to get the real local timezone. But the `Calendar` class of Java does that trick nicely.

As `DateFormat` you can also use your `SimpleDateFormat` if you like.

Comment: Or `TimeZone.getDefault()` which will return the time zone where the program is running. Eg. `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())`.

Comment: No. That would be wrong. TimeZone.getDefault() returns the local timezone in some implementations of Java, but for example OpenJDK 6 under Linux is reported to return ALWAYS the GMT timezone, no matter the real timezone.

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat` (and `SimpleDateFormat`) defaults to the JVM's timezone, which should be your computer's timezone.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM hh:mm");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Prints out in the local timezone. You can always explicitly set  `DateFormat`'s timezone by calling `setTimeZone`.

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
```

Comment: To my discomfort, even this is not working for me. Actually, none of the solutions offered are working. Interestingly, even eclipse is showing me the same date/time all the time which I am getting from these code. (My desktop is showing 10:35 PM (the correct local time) as I type this, whereas I am getting 5:05 PM). Am I missing something too trivial?

Comment: After specifying explicitly the timeZone in getTimeZone(), I am getting the correct result. Isn't the TimeZone.getDefault() supposed to return my local timezone?